# Trying to shut down pc but

Tags: shutdown, restart, 16.10

Hi I have a laptop with Ubuntu 16.10 dual-booted with Win7. So when I choose the option to shut the menu comes up but then it freezes like I can't choose anything but I can move my mouse around and open applications but I ccannot type please help!!
Ok I found out what was going on I had to use the arrows and click enter to reboot or shutdown but I dont want it like that, so is there a way I could use the mouse instead of keyboard?

Comment: It may be an application that's not shutting itself down properly. Do you have my-weather-indicator installed? If you can open the terminal app, type `top` and see if you can tell what the top application is, and that might also be a clue. Check on your "Startup Applications" and see if one of them is causing the problem. Cheers, Al

Comment: Oh yes I have "my-weather-indicator-applet" installed, so do I have to uninstall it? It's not a problem to uninstall it but I do need a weather application:) thanks for your time and effort, and sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Quit my-weather-indicator before shutting down, and see if that solves your shutdown problem. If it does, let me know, and I'll put it in the form of an answer which you can vote/accept. Cheers, Al

Answer (score -1):

Try the following command to force a system shutdown:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

This problem that you are experiencing might be a bug. You could report it here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity. You *will* need to create an Ubunut One account for this. The *will* most likely ask you to run a few commands to get sufficient debugging information.

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the problem. Trying to report a bug with this little information does no good at this time.

Comment: 'shutdown now' and 'shutdown -h now' are the same command as "-h equivalent to --poweroff, unless --halt is specified" and "-P, --poweroff Power-off the machine (the default)." As specified in the manpage for the shutdown command. 'man shutdown'

Comment: But I don't want to be doing that everything I shut down, I would like to do it the easy way